# Getting a gameObject position detail wrt to another gameObject in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I am currently developing a software in Unity3D and wanted to know if it is possible to get gameObject's position detail(x,y,z) wrt to another gameObject on which the first gameObject is placed.

For eg: If I place a vase above a table, I want to know the position of the vase based on the table.

**Edited - Further described about my query**

As per the example I mentioned, I want to place the vase on the table and then click a button ( I think that will be better to fetch though I'm not sure) to fetch the position details of the vase. Lets say the size of table is (30, 50, 20) and the vase is place 5unit above the table and in the middle. So, when I press the button ok, the value I should get is (15, 55, 10).

Will, it possible to get?

Comment: There are a variety of ways to determine this, so adding more specifics to your question would be helpful. When is this calculation meant to occur? How are objects made aware of each other - do they maintain a list of other objects, do they detect each other on collision, etc? If you code as much as you can and provide us with the part you can't figure out, it will help people give a more specific and useful answer to your scenario.

Comment: Right now, I don't have any code regarding it. As per the example I mentioned, I want to place the vase on the table and then click a button ( I think that will be better to fetch though I'm not sure) to fetch the position details of the vase. Lets say the size of table is (30, 50, 20) and the vase is place 5unit above the table and in the middle. So, when I press the button ok, the value I should get is (15, 55, 10). Will, it possible to get?

Answer (score -1):

Create a dictionary to link ur object id to the desired component(or game object then u can get any component from it), I recommend having the dictionary inside an SO because then u could just drag n drop to which one desires to know it. If you want to answer to changes the path is similar but u should register listeners to those objects and then u will need to expose your own APIs to apply changes and invoke the events or taper it through some property accessor. Hope this help

Comment: It is little confusing. Will it be possible to explain in a simpler way as I'm new in this?